# Using getState in java

Tags: java, getstate

I am new to programming and I just started working with Applets on `Java`. I saw the command getState and understand what it's doing to the specific code but I don't know what it actually does. What is the function of `getState()` command on `Java`? What do we use it for?

Comment: Google is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of the usage of getState() I found after searching:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.lang.*;

public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        // returns the state of this thread
        Thread.State state = Thread.currentThread().getState();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("state = " + state);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadDemo());

        // this will call run() function
        t.start();   
    }
}
```

Compiling and running gives us

```
Thread-0
state = RUNNABLE
```

Comment: what condition will not return state = other things ??